# How to check for a status and download file from a link to server in background php

Tags: php, download

I have an application where the user uploads a CSV or TXT file and my system verify emails from the file and then download the results to the upload directory. but sometimes if the file size is large like there are 1 million emails it takes some time to verify that file. and the download link of the file will not be available. In that case, I want to show the user that we are verifying his file. it can take several minutes and I know how to that. I need to know how to make a script that checks if the status does not equal finished then wait for some time and try again to download the file. Note: the script will go to a link and download the file with file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, fopen($url));

**Here is the function which downloads the file**

```
function downloadResultFilesInServer($file_id, $fileName) {
    $downloadURL = "https://bulkapi.millionverifier.com/bulkapi/v2/download";
    $key = VERIFIER_API_KEY;
    $url = $downloadURL . "?key=$key&file_id=$file_id&filter=";
    file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . "/" . $fileName . "_OK_ONLY.csv", fopen($url . "ok", 'r'));
    file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . "/" . $fileName . "_OK_AND_CATCH_ALL.csv", fopen($url . "ok_and_catch_all", 'r'));
    file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . "/" . $fileName . "_UNKNOWN.csv", fopen($url . "unknown", 'r'));
    file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . "/" . $fileName . "_INVALID.csv", fopen($url . "invalid", 'r'));
    file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . "/" . $fileName . "_FULL_REPORT.csv", fopen($url . "all", 'r'));
}
```

**Here are my conditions**

```
// If verification is in progress insert the details in db
if (in_array($o["status"],['in_progress'])) {
    $_SESSION['verifyInProgress'] = $o["file_id"];
    insertEmailListResultsInDatabase($userId, $o, $fileNameNew, $connection);

} elseif (in_array($o["status"],['canceled'])) {
    // if verification is cancelled show user alert
    echo "<script>alert('Verification was canceled by user')</script>";
}

if (!in_array($o["status"],['finished', 'canceled'])) {
    // keep trying to download file 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the file status, you should create a JavaScript method to call an endpoint that provides updated information about the status.

You can use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to call the server.

Here is a working example:

```js
var checkFile = setInterval(checkFileStatusOnServer, 5000); // Call the server every 5 seconds

function checkFileStatusOnServer() {

    const todoIds = [2, 3, 4];
    const randomId = todoIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * todoIds.length)];

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + randomId)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json.completed);
        const completed = Boolean(json.completed);
        if(completed) {
            alert('Download file!');
            clearInterval(checkFile);
        }
        return json.completed;
    });
}
```

On this API, only TODO ID 4 is completed. Let's consider this item as an example when the file is finally available to download.

**UPDATE**

You should change the URL in the fetch method with your actual implementation in PHP where you process the file and make it available for download as soon as it gets ready.

Comment: on completion can we use PHP functions in this?

Comment: No, because you still need to check if the file is available in the client side. Everything else you can do server side.